# Unknown column 'wp_cons_users.id' in 'on clause'

Tags: mysql

I have three table one is for users and other one is for subject and third one contain user_id, subject_id foreign keys.

I get unknow coloumn when I run the following sql.

```
SELECT wp_cons_users.first_name, wp_cons_subject.subject, wp_cons_skilllist.skill_level
FROM  `wp_cons_subject` 
JOIN wp_cons_skilllist ON wp_cons_skilllist.user_id = wp_cons_users.id
JOIN wp_cons_users ON wp_cons_users.id = wp_cons_skilllist.user_id
WHERE wp_cons_subject.id =  '1'
ORDER BY  `wp_cons_skilllist`.`skill_level` DESC
```

I can't find the error with this query.

wp_cons_skilllist

### column        link to

id (primay)
user_id  wp_cons_users -> id

subj_id  wp_cons_subject -> id
skill_level

---

Here I try to get the username, skill level and subject for any given subject id.

Comment: We will need to see the schema of the 3 tables to be able to help. What part of the above SQL query is the unknown column error?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your main problem is with the ordering of your JOINs. In your first join, you are matching with `wp_cons_users`.`id`, but you don't join that table until later in the query. If you re-order the joins it should work better. Also, based on your table description, it seems that you will also need to join on `subject_id`. This query should help:

```
SELECT wp_cons_users.first_name
, wp_cons_subject.subject
, wp_cons_skilllist.skill_level
FROM  wp_cons_users 
JOIN `wp_cons_subject`
ON wp_cons_users.id=`wp_cons_subject`.user_id
AND wp_cons_subject.id =  '1'
JOIN
wp_cons_skilllist 
ON wp_cons_skilllist.user_id = wp_cons_users.id
AND  wp_cons_skilllist.subject_id = `wp_cons_subject`.id
ORDER BY  `wp_cons_skilllist`.`skill_level` DESC
```

I am guessing about the field names that weren't in your original query, so you may have to make some changes if they're different from what I'm assuming.

Answer (score 0):

Without information about your attributes in your table, I'm afraid we can only assume that there is no ID column in your wp_cons_users table.

Answer (score 0):

when I corrected the query to following it started to work.

```
SELECT wp_cons_users.first_name, wp_cons_subject.subject, wp_cons_skilllist.skill_level
FROM  `wp_cons_skilllist` 
JOIN wp_cons_subject ON wp_cons_subject.id = wp_cons_skilllist.subject_id
JOIN wp_cons_users ON wp_cons_users.id = wp_cons_skilllist.user_id
WHERE wp_cons_skilllist.subject_id =  '1'
ORDER BY  `wp_cons_skilllist`.`skill_level` DESC 
LIMIT 0 , 30
```